# Unable to cover code for aggregate results function

Tags: unit-test

here I am trying to cover code for aggregate function. Here I am providing class code and test class, anyone have any clues why unable to cover.

```java
public class ChartdataCon {

    public Integer allLeads{get;set;}
    public Integer TtlLeadNtQfy{get;set;}
    public Integer TtlQfyLeads{get;set;}  

    public ChartdataCon(){
        leadDetails();
    }

    public void  leadDetails(){
        for( AggregateResult ar :[select count(id) total FROM Lead]){
            allLeads = integer.valueOf(ar.get('total'));
        }
        for( AggregateResult ar : [select count(id) total,Status FROM Lead GROUP BY Status]){
            if(ar.get('Status') == 'Qualified'){
                TtlQfyLeads =  integer.valueOf(ar.get('total'));
            }
            if(ar.get('Status') == 'Not Qualified'){
                TtlLeadNtQfy=  integer.valueOf(ar.get('total'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my TEST CLASS

```java
@isTest
public class ChartdataConTest {
    static void Testdata() {
        Lead ld = new Lead(
            Owner__c = 'Nadal',
            Status = 'Qualified'
        );

        insert ld;
        Test.startTest();
        Chartdatacon chart = new ChartdataCon();

        system.assertEquals(chart.count(),100);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that test compile and pass? Your `ChartDataCon` class does not have a `count()` method.

Comment: Yes, but showing code coverage as 0%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method

```
static void Testdata() {
```

is not annotated with the `@isTest` or `testMethod` annotations. As such, it's not treated as a unit test and executed during test runs, and does not provide coverage. Add the annotation and rerun the test.

Comment: And one more thing I just want to add is that Aggregate Result functions don't need a separate test class. Able to get 100% code coverage now, Thank you!! David for correcting me.

Comment: Aggregate queries do need to be covered, @Laxman.